# Mongodb query to sort objects with a list of ID's

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a function that returns a list of ID's.
The list of ID's is important and I need to extract the data from collection and have it sorted in the same order that the list is in.
For e.g: My list of ID's is: `[id8,id5,id4,id9,id3]`.
I run a pymongo query like: `db.collection.find({"_id":{"$in":[ObjectId(i) for i in list]}})`.
However this messes up the list order. I need to get the objects in the same order like `id8,id5,id4,id9,id3.`

I tried using an aggregate function too:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
            {"$match":{"_id": {"$in": [ObjectId(_id) for _id in list]}}},
            { "$addFields" : {"__order":{"$indexOfArray":[list, "$_id"]}}},
            { "$sort" : { "__order" : 1 } }
        ])
```

However, even this returns the same order of objects.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are supplementing `[ObjectId(_id) for _id in list]` for the `$match` while `list` for the `$addFields`. Other than this inconsistency, [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NZLZKIv_ltv) is my trial to replicate your work and it seems fine to me.

Comment: The reason I'm supplementing `[ObjectId(_id) for _id in list]` is because as opposed to simple strings, my Id's are stored in `ObjectId(id)` format. Also, the reason I'm adding the `list`to `$addFields` is because I want to get the query output sorted in the same format as my list is in. Your example did not work for me because the ID's are stored as `ObjectId(ID)` as opposed to `ID` in string format

Comment: I think the key is that you need to supplement both 2 arguments as list of objectIds consistently. [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EzcvjlMxiJ_) is a modified playground from the previous version to use objectId for `_id`.

Comment: If `list` contains strings but `$_id` contains ObjectID, the `$indexOfArray` will be the same (not found) for all of the documents, right?